# Functional derivative simplification for effective action derivation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, correlation-functions, functional-derivatives

I am following Das' Finite Temperature Field Theory and the discussion of the effective potential. Das defines,
\begin{equation}
S^J
=
\int d^4x
\left[
\frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi - \frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2 - \frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4 + J\phi
\right]
=
S + \int d^4x\ J\phi.
\end{equation}
The generating functional is naturally,
\begin{equation}
Z[J] = e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}W[J]} = \int\mathcal{D}\phi e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}S^J}
.
\end{equation}
From the equations of motion, we have
\begin{equation}
(\square + m^2)\phi + \frac{\lambda}{3!}\phi^3 - J = 0.
\end{equation}
We will denote this as $F(\phi) = J$. Now, consider $\phi\to\phi + \delta\phi$. We naturally know then that $\delta Z[J] = 0$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
0 &= \int \mathcal{D}\phi\ \frac{\delta S^J}{\delta \phi}e^{iS^J}\\[0.25cm]
&= 
\int \mathcal{D}\phi\ (F(\phi) - J)e^{iS^J}\\[0.25cm]
&= 
\int \mathcal{D}\phi\ \left(F\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{\delta}{\delta J} \right) - J\right)e^{iS^J}\\[0.25cm]
&= 
\left(F\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{\delta}{\delta J} \right) - J\right)Z[J]
.
\end{align}
In terms of $W[J]$,
\begin{equation}
e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}W[J]}F\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{\delta}{\delta J} \right)e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}W[J]}
=
J(x)
.
\end{equation}

Das then goes on to say that this is equivalent to,
\begin{equation}
F\left(
\frac{\delta W}{\delta J(x)}
+
\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\delta}{\delta J(x)}
\right)
 = J(x)
\end{equation}
where "here, we are assuming that the functional derivative, after simplification, actions on the identity on the right."

I am not sure how this final result is obtained. I would appreciate any input.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/544922/2451